# ibus-table-latex trigger keybinding (or just documentation in general)

Tags: ibus, shortcut-keys, input-method

I’ve installed the [`ibus-table-latex` package via APT](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-table-others) and it works fine. However, I don’t see a way to re-bind (or disable) some of the triggers (backslash `\`, `_`, `^`) that open the “candidate list”. In particular, I’d like to get rid of `^` and `_` doing anything special.

In the input method setup, I’ve found this “Key bindings” page:

[image: ibus-table-latex preferences/setup]

but these triggers are nowhere in that list.

More generally (but perhaps this warrants a separate question), is there any documentation for `ibus-table-latex` that would explain how or whether these can be changed? The only things I’ve found are

- [The `ibus-table-others` GitHub page](https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others)
- A short sentence on the [IBus Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus#ibus-table)
- The [“About” button gives this link](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-table/) ([there’s also this one with identical content](https://kaio.net/ibus-table/)), which is devoid of any information

Comment: When I see [the source of that tool](https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others/blob/main/tables/latex.txt), it seems like the special meaning of the `^` and `_` characters is hard coded. Possibly that file can serve as a kind of documentation too, even if it's not very user friendly. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the latex table itself, not in the settings of ibus-table.
The latex table contains:

https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others/blob/main/tables/latex.txt#L60

```
### Start characters, every key in the table starts with one of these characters
START_CHARS = \_^
```

So if you want to change that behaviour you could make your own changed latex table.

Comment: Indeed, I had figured that out in the meantime, and meant to write an answer myself. Thanks!