# How to stop automatic candidate insertion with ibus-table?

Tags: ibus, input-method

I’m using `ibus-table` (specifically, `ibus-table-latex`) and would like to disable the following behavior:
When I start typing something that triggers `ibus-table`’s candidate list (e. g. any part of `\rightarrow`, such as `\rightar`), the candidate list opens and the best-matching candidate is already “pre-selected” for insertion.
See the following screenshot:

[image: ibus-table-latex input example]

My problem is that even when I press a key that’s not in the “valid input characters” list, such as `%` or `!`, this pre-selected top candidate is inserted instead of what I typed.
So, for example, typing `\rightarr!` results in `→!`, but what I want is for the text to appear exactly as entered in this case.

I’ve tried a few different options:

- I’ve noticed that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does something similar to what I want (not sure where this comes from; it’s nowhere on the key bindings tab in the preferences): It preserves the text typed in so far and closes the candidate list. However, I don’t want to have to press a special key to do this.
- The “commit to preedit” key binding (default: <kbd>Shift</kbd>) is somewhat similar, but instead of using the characters entered so far, it “auto-completes” the text for the current candidate, but without replacing it with the corresponding symbol. It doesn’t look like this could work for what I want.
- The “cancel” key binding (default: <kbd>Esc</kbd>) doesn’t select the candidate, but gets rid of the entered text entirely, so that’s not helpful.
- The “commit” key binding (default: <kbd>Space</kbd>) just uses the top candidate immediately.

Another potentially relevant thing I’ve found is the “Auto select” setting in the preferences:

[image: ibus-table-latex preferences]

However, this is set to “No”, so I don’t think this is causing my problem.

Comment: Please don't spam Ask Ubuntu with multiple questions on the same topic. You already submitted https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455600 . Instead of submitting a new question, you should have edited the other one.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Excuse me? These are completely separate questions. Are you saying that merely because I mentioned `ibus-table-latex` in both of them, that I should just put everything in one big question?

Comment: Maybe I didn't read carefully enough. My apologies. If I was you, I'd ask for documentation in an issue at github. I know the maintainer from other projects, and he is usually very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Gunnar Hjalmarsson, I have [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others/issues/26) to ask about this. It seems like this is (currently) not possible without modifying the code for `ibus-table`, but the [necessary changes are minimal](https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others/issues/26#issuecomment-1438820576) and can easily be done manually:

```
diff --git a/engine/table.py b/engine/table.py
index 6953e6f..4dcdc7a 100644
--- a/engine/table.py
+++ b/engine/table.py
@@ -4172,7 +4172,7 @@ class TabEngine(IBus.EngineSimple): # type: ignore
             if DEBUG_LEVEL > 0:
                 LOGGER.debug(
                     'trailing invalid input: keychar=%s', keychar)
-            if not self._candidates:
+            if not self._candidates or True:
                 self.commit_string(self.get_preedit_tabkeys_complete())
             else:
                 self.commit_to_preedit()
```